# jQuery Different Classes - Poll Options Selected 1st, 2nd, 3rd

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selection

**SEE UPDATE BELOW**

First of all, thanks for any help! I'm in a bind and banging my head against the wall, because I'm really new to JS and can't figure this out.

Basically, I have a poll that allows a maximum of 3 checkboxes to be checked. The checkboxes are not visible, but are hidden and I'm using images for selecting. The output is laid out like this:

```
<div id="options">
  <div class="option">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="rank-answer-#" class="mycheckbox" />
    <img src"..." />
  </div>
  ...more <div class="options"> repeating with same format...
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when a user selects the first option, the overlay DIV populates with a 1, and when they select a 2nd, the overlay div for that option populates with a 2, and so on and so forth for the 3rd option. This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(".mycheckbox").click(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        var overlaydiv = jQuery(this).prev().attr("class");
        jQuery('.' + overlaydiv).html(#);
    }
  });
});
```

That's all I have. I don't really know where to go from there. Thanks again for your help!

EDITED: Via Disha V.'s suggestion.

**EDITED (UPDATE):**

So, I've changed the structure and the jQuery and am getting kind of close, but am unable to get quite there. Here's what I have as far as structure goes.

```
<div class="option">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkform" class="oneselect1" />
</div>
<div class="option">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkform" class="oneselect1" />
</div>
<div class="option">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkform" class="oneselect1" />
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery I have:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.oneselect1').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).addClass('checked1');
        $(this).removeClass('oneselect1');
        $('.oneselect1').addClass('twoselect2');
        $('.twoselect2').removeClass('oneselect1');
    }
   });
});

jQuery(function($){
  $('.twoselect2').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).addClass('checked2');
        $(this).removeClass('twoselect2');
        $(this).removeClass('checked1');
        $('.twoselect2').addClass('threeselect3');
        $('.threeselect3').removeClass('twoselect2');
    }
  });
});

jQuery(function($){
  $('.threeselect3').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).addClass('checked3');
        $(this).removeClass('threeselect3');
        $(this).removeClass('checked2');
        $('.threeselect3').addClass('noselect');
        $('.noselect').removeClass('threeselect3');
    }
  });
});
```

When I checked the first box, everything changes correctly. When I check the second box, nothing changes, except checkbox1 is added to the 2nd checkbox as well. If I nest those inside each other, it runs correctly, until I uncheck one of them. You can see the JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tylerjohnson/c0fo05ct/). And you can see it nested [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tylerjohnson/sh6ujnh9/).

As you can see, I can remove the additional classes that are added, but when I uncheck it's gets really messy. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Add class "mycheckbox" to checkbox and remove function, added attribute `rank` to get order of which checkbox is checked

```
<input type="checkbox" id="rank-answer-#" class="mycheckbox" rank="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="rank-answer-#" class="mycheckbox" rank="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="rank-answer-#" class="mycheckbox" rank="3" />
```

You should write code in document ready like below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery(".mycheckbox").click(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            var overlaydiv = jQuery(this).prev().attr("class");
            jQuery('.' + overlaydiv).html(#);
            alert(jQuery(this).attr("rank")); // alerts rank of checkbox
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll do that. :) Any idea how to get which is checked first, second, third?

Comment: That's getting me closer, so thanks! I need it to be based on what the user clicks first, though. So, for instance, if they click the 3rd checkbox, that'd be ranked 1st. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Found something perfect to show what I'm trying to do! See the poll here: http://www.breitbart.com/primary/. I'm trying to get the functionality where, if you click on one of the options, a 1 appears, then if you click on the 2nd option, a 2 appears.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine, who's good with JS/jQuery, wrote me this bit of code, which works amazingly!

```
(function ($) {
var form = $( "#form");
var choiceClasses = [ "choice1", "choice2", "choice3" ];
form.on( "change", "input:checkbox", function ( e ) {
    var parentContainer = $(this).parent();
    if ( parentContainer.is( "[class*='choice']" ) ) {
        var classes = parentContainer.attr( "class" );
        var choice = classes.split( " " ).find( function ( v ) {
            return v.match( /choice[0-9]+/ );
        });
        choiceClasses.unshift( choice );
        choiceClasses.sort();
        parentContainer.removeClass( choice );
    } else {
        parentContainer.addClass( choiceClasses.shift() );
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

You can see a fiddle of it in action **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/tylerjohnson/qvqay9sx/)**.